# How to get JSON from URL in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, url

I am doing an Ajax call with this set of data:

```
"type":"alter",
"param":{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

In PHP, I handle this by:

• Getting `file_get_contents('php://input')`:

```
type=alter&param%5Bkey1%5D=value1&param%5Bkey2%5D=value2
```

• URL decoding and slicing it by `&`:

```
[
    "type=alter",
    "param[key1]=value1",
    "param[key2]=value2"
]
```

• Further slicing each of these by `=`:

```
[
    [
        "type",
        "alter"
    ],
    [
        "param[key1]",
        "value1"
    ],
    [
        "param[key2]",
        "value2"
    ]
]
```

• Then creating an object `$data` with each index 0 as key and index 1 as value:

```
$data = array(
    "type"=>"alter",
    "param[key1]"=>"value1",
    "param[key2]"=>"value2"
)
```

Question:

This was not a problem when my data set in Ajax was strictly `key=value`, but it gets messy when I add arrays or objects as values. I want to handle the data set in PHP as it appears in the Ajax. My desired outcome is:

```
$data = array(
    "type"=>"alter",
    "param"=>array(
        "key1"=>"value1",
        "key2"=>"value2"
    )
)
```

so that when I get `$data['param']`, it will give me all the param keys. I could do it manually, but I thought there might be an easier method to do this. Especially if I could get my desired object from `file_get_contents('php://input')` right away.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this is possibly the most complicated way possible? Surely it's got to be easier using `$_GET` (or `$_POST`) and `json_decode`?

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Your data is form url encoded. You can just read it straight from `$_POST` where it will have been parsed automatically.

Comment: I'm using `file_get_contents('php://input')` because the data I get back is universally used for GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods.

@iainn.. Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Eyzi — `$_POST` is not related to the POST request method, despite the name. It will populate for any request with a properly encoded body with the right content-type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an inbuilt function to parse parameter strings: [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
<?php
$in = 'type=alter&param%5Bkey1%5D=value1&param%5Bkey2%5D=value2';

parse_str($in, $data);

print_r($data);

/*
Array
(
    [type] => alter
    [param] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
*/
```

If you can access $_POST then do so, you could also check $_POST is empty before doing it.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST)) {
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_POST);
    }

    print_r($_POST);

    /*
    Array
    (
        [type] => alter
        [param] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value1
                [key2] => value2
            )

    )

    */
}
```